# I just locked myself out of my Access database

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I just locked myself out of my access database. I made a login form with a username and password. Then I was stupid enough to make an on close command that does `DoCmd.CloseDatabase`.

Now I can't get into my database any more because it closes the entire database every time I want to do something. Is there anyway to fix this? I cant open any forms and I can't get into the design view of the login form. Can I delete the login form in some other way?

Comment: Ages since I used Access, but it used to be true that if you held the Shift Key at the same time as clicking a button, no code was actioned.  This might let you get back into design mode

Comment: If all else fails, create a new database and import all the objects from your existing one apart from the login form!

Comment: Thanks for the input Jonathan. I got it working using alt + f11 and then i just removed the code that caused the problem in vba. Now its all working again! Thank you for your time!

Comment: The shift key will do the trick as Jonathan says.  I've used as my first line in the past, if environ("username")=myusername then stop  this stops anything happening, you have to press F5 to continue, but it stops the code running :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out how to do it. You can access VBA with the keyboard shortcut Alt + F11 on windows. Then you can just remove the code and save and its working again!